# How do I show each character in TextArea when it is typed in TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am trying to show every character instantly into `TextArea` as and when it is typed into the `TextField`.

I've written some code as follows but it didn't work:

**Application_Controler.java**

```
public class Application_Controler {

    @FXML
    private TextField txt;

    @FXML
    private TextArea showTxt;

    @FXML
    void keyTyped(ActionEvent event) {
        String text = txt.getText();
        String oldText = showTxt.getText();
        String nextText = oldText+text;
        showTxt.setText(nextText);
    }

}
```

Here is the `.fxml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="imran.jfx.application.Application_Controler">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="-17.0" layoutY="-14.0" prefHeight="461.0" prefWidth="454.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txt" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="87.0" onKeyTyped="#keyTyped" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="229.0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="showTxt" layoutX="56.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="210.0" prefWidth="362.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Your question is not really very clear. Do you want the `TextField` and `TextArea` to *always* have exactly the same text? If not, what do you actually mean? What do you want to happen in the text area if the user deletes text in the text field?

Comment: I think u understood. Yes, I want the TextField and TextArea to always have exactly the same text. I want when a character is typed into the TextField it will be instantly shown into the TextArea. 

If I type 'a' into TextField then instantly 'a' should be shown into the TextArea as output. Then if I type "aba" it should be shown into the TextArea as output. Hope you clearly understand now.

Can you help me now?

Comment: In that case the answer already posted will do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the `textProperty() of TextField` to the `textProperty() of TextArea`.

```
textArea.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
```

Try adding the following code inside the `initialize()` of your controller :

```
public class Application_Controler implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txt;

    @FXML
    private TextArea showTxt;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         showTxt.textProperty().bind(txt.textProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry can write a more details please?

I did as follows:  
public void initialize() {
     showTxt.textProperty().bind(txt.textProperty());
    }

Comment: I need one more help.

I've some images into the project folder. Each image has a name ex: a, aa, aba etc.

I want to show the related image into ImageView when it matches an image name typed into the TextField.

Please help me to do it.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question you have asked before. If you have another issue, please ask a new question.